# Cannot remove last field from input in panel

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

In Flask panel I have class which inherits embedded document and I have inside

```
persons = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Person', required=False, null=True), default=[], required=False)
```

When I want to remove last Person from my input field via Flask Admin Panel it saves document but do not remove, when I have two I can remove one, but cannot stay empty when I try to remove second. I tried different combinations with flags and I put breakpoints  in pre_save and post_save but in both cases when I remove last Person it shows that person is still inside. How to remove this constraint from Form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that nothing happens on flask-admin side when you submit a form with an empty list. So I did a trick using on_model_change method, it would look like this in your case :

```
  def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):         
    if not 'persons' in request.form :                        
        model.persons = []
```